# Using :valid in CSS

Tags: css, pseudo-class

Is using `:valid` in CSS necessary to include in a stylesheet or will the web browsers already know that something is valid?
I've already written something like this

```
input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=number], textarea,
    fieldset {
    /* required to properly style form 
   elements on WebKit based browsers */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 90%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input:invalid {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px red;
}

input:focus:invalid {
    outline: none;
}
```

I used `:invalid` in my code already.

Comment: If you're referring to HTML5 validation, it will mark the fields `:valid` or `:invalid`. If you'd like to specifically style these inputs, then you can include definitions for them in your stylesheet as you have above. That said, I'm not sure I really understand the question - CSS is **solely for styling purposes**. [A simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/3zfj0ktr/) - i've used the `:invalid` pseudo-selector to add a red border to the input when it's empty.

Comment: I generally only **style** `:invalid` in CSS  just to bring attention to it and leave `:valid` alone. - [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid)